# Converting Keras Model to TFJS: Weights are different

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow.js, tensorflowjs-converter

I've converted a Keras .H5 model to a TFJS Layers Model to infer on a Node JS server and am noticing wildly different results between the two. This model is used for image classification and uses a slightly modified Xception architecture. Both the [model.summary()](https://pastebin.com/A2sy2Qe4) for Python and the [model.summary()](https://pastebin.com/n1Zn9LR0) for TFJS match up, so it seems the conversion of the architecture has been successful.

After looking into it further, the weights for the first layer of the model are completely different between the two which would explain the different results. The [input image tensor](https://pastebin.com/kmbtr8wP) is consistent between both, meaning the problem should lie with the weights.

[Here](https://pastebin.com/6NpBWM2w) is a link to a comparison of the same layer's weights in TFJS and Keras...

I set the output of my Express HTTP file server to verbose to check whether all of the weight files were being fetched, and I noticed that they were all being fetched, but in an unsequential order:

```
GET /model.json 200 91907 - 6.784 ms
GET /group1-shard20of20.bin 200 3770536 - 32.671 ms
GET /group1-shard4of20.bin 200 4194304 - 26.951 ms
GET /group1-shard7of20.bin 200 4194304 - 26.805 ms
GET /group1-shard14of20.bin 200 4194304 - 24.868 ms
GET /group1-shard10of20.bin 200 4194304 - 27.278 ms
GET /group1-shard1of20.bin 200 4194304 - 24.847 ms
GET /group1-shard16of20.bin 200 4194304 - 24.827 ms
GET /group1-shard11of20.bin 200 4194304 - 27.032 ms
GET /group1-shard19of20.bin 200 4194304 - 25.132 ms
GET /group1-shard17of20.bin 200 4194304 - 25.369 ms
GET /group1-shard8of20.bin 200 4194304 - 24.850 ms
GET /group1-shard6of20.bin 200 4194304 - 26.229 ms
GET /group1-shard3of20.bin 200 4194304 - 26.584 ms
GET /group1-shard12of20.bin 200 4194304 - 26.231 ms
GET /group1-shard9of20.bin 200 4194304 - 26.123 ms
GET /group1-shard5of20.bin 200 4194304 - 25.837 ms
GET /group1-shard2of20.bin 200 4194304 - 27.055 ms
GET /group1-shard13of20.bin 200 4194304 - 26.368 ms
GET /group1-shard15of20.bin 200 4194304 - 26.650 ms
GET /group1-shard18of20.bin 200 4194304 - 33.848 ms
```

Could this be why my weights are out of order and inconsistent with the original weights from the Keras model?

I noticed some [issues](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/issues/784) like this arose almost a year ago, but the bug was identified and an update to Tensorflow solved it for these people.

I am using Tensorflow JS 1.2.11 to load the model on a Node JS v10.16.3 server, and I used Tensorflow 1.14 under Python 3.7 to convert the model. This is the code I used to convert the model:

```
tfjs.converters.save_keras_model(model, path)
```

And this is how I load the model into TFJS:

```
model = await tf.loadLayersModel('http://127.0.0.1:3001/model.json');
```

Thanks for your time and expertise,

```
model.getWeights()[0].print();
Tensor
    [[0.0063044 , 0.0171392 ],
     [0.0730571 , -0.0162974],
     [-0.0392024, 0.0501709 ],
     ...,
     [0.0321253 , 0.0204812 ],
     [-0.045588 , -0.0343406],
     [0.0232343 , -0.0127071]]

Python:
>>> nn.get_weights()[0]
array([[[[ 4.01871502e-01,  6.77069500e-02, -9.92160812e-02,
          -2.40881741e-01,  4.94409263e-01, -1.35092044e+00,
          -7.53455386e-02, -1.15802072e-01,  2.54089713e-01,
           4.12381589e-01, -2.02945337e-01, -5.65736771e-01,
           ...
```

If it helps, [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PB0AcmG3za0MvAQMACQWy3Hl2HKc0emR/view?usp=sharing) is a link to the Python and TFJS model files.

Comment: The weights don't have the same shape. That will not be the case if the layers have the same shape

Comment: Yeah, that’s strange, the weights should be four dimensional to match the input. Could this be due to the weights being exported incorrectly by the TensorFlow JS converter?

Comment: I don't think so. Since you are saying that the model summaries match, the layers weight shape should match as well. Unless, you are not printing the model weight correctly ...

Comment: I’m displaying the Python model’s weights just using the interactive console with no print function but the TFJS weights are printed by the Numpy print() function so maybe there’s a difference there? That might be why the decimal values are different... maybe the wrong dimension is being printed/used?

Comment: Can you print the model weight directly in the js (respectively in python) code ?

Comment: The closest I could get to directly printing the weights (and not using the TensorFlow print() method) in JavaScript was console.log(model.getWeights()[0].dataSync()); as just logging the weights simply shows the attributes of the tensor. I did the equivalent in Python - print(model.get_weights()[0]). The results were very similar to before, with the Python weights being different to the TFJS ones, and in four dimensions, not two.

Comment: Also, Tensorflow JS stated that the shape of the first layer's weights is [ 2048, 2 ], whilst Python's weights are in the shape [3, 3, 3, 32].

Comment: Maybe you can add both models summary to the question

Comment: Yep, both outputs are now in the question.

Comment: You can open a new issue on github